# Get data from JSON object inside Angular Component

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

i'm trying to get a username from a JSON object but i can't access, this is the function where i tried to get the username :

```
 getUser()
 {
   if(this.authService.username)
   {
      var username:String;

      /// get the username from this.authService.username
      console.log(this.authService.username);
    }
}
```

when i print this.authService.username to console i get this result

```
Object { username: "user", roles: Array[1], token: "user:1499017418257:d6212d3f1ac7251a…", status: "OK" }
```

all i want is to stock the value of username so i can use it . Any suggestions? thanks

i am using ionic by the way.

Comment: `this.authservice['username']` is not safe but should work.

Comment: So you want `return this.authService.username;` to be the body of your getUser() method? I fail to understand what the problem is. Maybe it's the bad naming that confuses you? this.authService.username is not a user name. It's a user object, that contains a username. So it should be renamed to `user`.

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing the user object in getUser(), renaming that variable will help make it more clear:

```
getUser()
 {
   if(this.authService.userOb)
   {
      console.log(this.authService.userOb.username);
    }
}
```